# How to load `stack ghci` without compiling & linking the whole project?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

Does for anyone else `stack` compile & link the whole project when only `stack ghci` is asked for?

Shouldn't it skip the former and jump into `ghci` right away to load sources? I've observed it to do both for me on most of my projects and therefore it's doing seemingly superfluous work. Is this by design, or might have I misconfigured some of my stack projects?

Perhaps is this done by `cabal` underneath without `stack` asking for it?

And at any rate, is there something I could do to skip the compilation + linking when I just want to enter `stack ghci`?

Comment: Which version of stack are you using?  Since version 1.3.0, the --no-build flag shouldn't be as necessary - it will skip a full build and instead only run the "initial build steps" necessary.

Comment: I have been using 1.1.2 mostly as of now. I've installed and tried 1.3.0 alongside, but an issue has kept me from using it -- it eludes what exactly right now. I'm glad to read what you write, that gives me more of a motivation to switch over.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Haskell Tool Stack Documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/ghci/):

> **Speeding up initial load**
>
> There are two ways to speed up the initial startup of ghci:
>
> - `--no-build`, to skip an initial build step. This only works if the dependencies have already been built.

You can also have `stack ghci` skip loading sources (if you know you only want one file loaded in, and can do it by hand) by using:

> - `--no-load`, to skip loading all defined modules into ghci. You can then directly use `:load MyModule` to load a specific module in your project.

Comment: Thanks! The `--no-build` flag may be what I've been looking for! Giving it a try now.

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized that `-fobject-code` may also play a part in this. I'm unsure where it is being set (not on the command line, not in the `.cabal`/`package.yaml` file and not in `~/.ghci` either).

Nevertheless when I negate it with `--ghci-options=-fbyte-code` the recompilation doesn't seem to be taking place.

I still hope to hear others' responses as I'd like to understand more thoroughly why the `-fobject-code` may require minutes for full recompilation on initial load, since `:reload`ing only takes about a second after a file has changed. (E.g. with `ghcid` too.)